# Fields are empty but form is still submitting. Although JS Validation is applied

Tags: javascript, html

**I HAVE SEEN**
similar questions & applies suggested solutions too but do not working :(
As Title Explained
i applied Java script validation but on submit button click form is submitted while fields are empty

here is the script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{

   if( document.form1.name.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your name!" );
     document.form1.name.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.form1.pass.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your Password!" );
     document.form1.pass.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   return( true );
}
</script>
```

Form is like

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="registered.php" onsubmit="return(validate());">
<p align="center">Username : 
<label for="name"></label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</p>
<p align="center">Password : 
<label for="pass"></label>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
</p>
<p align="center">
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like your code works :S [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcbyN/)

Comment: @nderscore Thanks for testing dude but it was not working on localhost. + i have not added registere.php file may be it demands it differently any how i got it edited thanks to Sachin & to you too for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the elements value using `form` then use something like this

```
document.forms['form1'].elements['name'].value
```

So change your condition like this

```
if(document.forms['form1'].elements['name'].value == "" )
{ 
  alert( "Please provide your name!" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. It's working (Y) I will accept your answer it says you can after 9 mins so i m waiting for 9 mins & will approve it :) Thanks again